# How can I turn this motor in CW or CCW direction using a DC supply mechanically?

Tags: power, batteries, motor, dc, mechanical

I want to Move this small metal plate attached to the motor from point A to point B if initially, it was touching point A **AND**  from point B to point A if initially, the plate was touching B

[See the diagram for understanding]

All the points T1, T2, T3, T4, T5 can be used as terminals to supply power if necessary here

I want to do this using a Battery on pressing a button till it reaches either of points A or B

T3 is the metal plate that can be used as a terminal through the body of the motor

I prefer using the mechanical method over the usage of ICs or transistors or Arduinos, etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advanced : )

[image: Project Pictorial Representation]

Comment: There are a wide variety of ways of getting reciprocating motion mechanically, with or without hitting some kind of a reversing lever etc. however none of them are on-topic here. A pair of momentary switches and a relay or two could be used to do it electromechanically or two N.O. SPST limit switches, half a quad gate package, and a DPDT relay with a few parts to drive it.

Comment: Thanks, @SpehroPefhany. Now I think the easiest way to do this would be by using an arduino mini board as @ Transistor has answered my question stating it cannot be done mechanically using simple components

Comment: An Arduino would just take the place of the DIP-14 gate, so similar number of components but far more flexible.

Comment: This isn't an electrical engineering question since you want a mechanical solution. That said, you can do this without ICs, transistors, Arduinos, or any semiconductors. How you do it us to wire up four SPST relays (or two DPDT relays) in an H-bridge circuit (similar to transistors) and connect your limit switches accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You will need some components to

- remember the button press during the transition.
- prevent automatic reversal and starting the reverse journey when a contact is made.
- alternate the direction when a contact is made.

If you are prepared to use relays then edit your question to explain that and to explain further what you are trying to achieve. You also need to cover the case when the circuit is powered up and T3 is touching neither A or B.

Really you need to consider some sort of programmable logic and Arduino-style microcontroller board is an easy one to work with.

Comment: It does not have to remember button press as the button will be pressed till it reaches either of the points

Comment: Both the points will have small neodymium magnets to hold the plate in place which would somehow complete the circuit and disconnect the battery to stop the motor movement IF this is all possible

Comment: btw, thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer but I recommend you unaccept for a day or two to encourage other answers. Someone might come up with something clever. The neodymium magnets will require a very high torque to pull apart. It's unlikely that an ungeared motor of the type shown could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The motor must accelerate then brake to stop at zero velocity and it cannot do that at the point of contact where you want to stop, unless you apply a low voltage just enough to start moving then short out the motor using a SPDT switch just before contacting the metal plate. But then you won’t be able to reverse it unless apply the reverse voltage with a DPDT relay then disable the short and connect to the DPDT relays and repeat to the other end with another lever type switch before the contact plate.  Obviously some logic is needed in wiring this but the short will brake the motor quickly.

By experimenting with a power amp and pulse you can test for variable pulse widths to see how much you can control the rotation angle with a pulse using a near 0 Ohm source impedance relative to the motor DCR. Then you might consider another way to speed up the process such as with a geared motor.  If that doesn’t make sense try starting your car in 5th gear.